# How to SUM all the values in a field?

Tags: modelbuilder, fields-attributes

I am intersecting a base road layer with 6 separate road layers to create 6 line feature outputs. I am using Model Builder for this. 
I was wondering is there a way I can SUM all of the values in a field for each of the separate road layers output?
My other option is to export the road output attribute tables to excel and make the calculation there but I'd much rather if I could add such a calculation to model builder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) GP tool for that.

Another thing you could do is to use [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000) GP tool to use the Use Ratio Policy option to summarize you fields as needed when running Intersect.